# Setting up htaccess to display background page on request

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Please, don't be offended if this seem quite easy but am new to `htaccess` file usage and I was wondering,if I could get help to accomplish something like below:

When a user types a username on my site like **www.mysite.com/cindy** , instead of displaying the page not found error it will load a page to display a profile with the `username` in the `url`.

Answer (score 0):

## In .htaccess :

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]

Additionally :

You need to create controller.php file which will accept parameter **username** from the URL, fetch the user data based upon that username and will show the user profile view.